# expl3 empty token list

Tags: expl3

Im sure this must be something very simple but it is eluding me.

The following code outputs `F`. Shouldn't it output `T`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn


\tl_new:N \otherlist
\tl_clear_new:N \otherlist

\tl_if_empty:nTF {\otherlist} {T} {F}


\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\tl_if_empty:NTF \otherlist` would give T, but ìn `\tl_if_empty:nTF {\otherlist}` the "n" contains `\otherlist`.

Comment: Off-topic: `\tl_clear_new:N \otherlist` isn't necessary

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The test `\tl_if_empty:NTF \l_bob_otherlist_tl {}{}` sees just the empty token list `\l_bob_otherlist_tl`, but `\tl_if_empty:nTF {\l_bob_otherlist_tl} {}{}` sees one token in the 'list' delimited by `{...}`.

See the difference for example with the `\tl_count:n` and `\tl_count:N` macros:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn


\tl_new:N \l_bob_otherlist_tl


First:  \tl_if_empty:nTF \l_bob_otherlist_tl {T} {F}
\par
Second: \tl_if_empty:NTF \l_bob_otherlist_tl {T} {F}
\par
Third: \tl_if_empty:nTF {\l_bob_otherlist_tl} {T} {F}
\par
\par
Counting~with~n: \tl_count:n {\l_bob_otherlist_tl}
\par
Counting~with~N: \tl_count:N \l_bob_otherlist_tl
\tl_set:Nn \l_bob_otherlist_tl {Foo}
\par
After~setting:\par
First:  \tl_if_empty:nTF \l_bob_otherlist_tl {T} {F}
\par
Second: \tl_if_empty:NTF \l_bob_otherlist_tl {T} {F}
\par
Third: \tl_if_empty:nTF {\l_bob_otherlist_tl} {T} {F}
\par
Counting~with~n: \tl_count:n {\l_bob_otherlist_tl}
\par
Counting~with~N: \tl_count:N \l_bob_otherlist_tl


\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

The `\tl_clear_new:N` isn't necessary since `\tl_new:N` already provides an empty, clean list.